# pygame strings doubling and flickering

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, spi

I have had an issue with this code for a HUD while skiing. The temperature has
a double string and the velocity when zero is blank. What is the problem here?
For windspeed and temperature reading, I am using a winspeed sensor by modern electronics, windsensor Rev C.

```
# coding=UTF-8

import pygame
import sys
import datetime
import math
import numpy
import thread
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from adxl345 import ADXL345
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
from picamera import PiCamera
import Adafruit_MCP3008
import random
volts = 0
CLK = 18
MISO = 20
MOSI = 21
CS = 8
mcp = Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(clk=CLK, cs=CS, miso=MISO, mosi=MOSI)
temp=0
angle = 0
velocity = 0         







def draw_borders(screen):
    #Draws some simple borders to the display""
    pygame.draw.lines(screen, (255, 255, 255), False, [(0, 30), (width, 30)], 2)

def draw_time(screen):
    #Draws the time to the display""
    the_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_as_string = the_time.strftime('%H:%M')
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 42)
    text = font.render(time_as_string, 1, (255, 255, 255))
    textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=screen.get_width()/2, centery=15)
    screen.blit(text, textpos)  # paste the text into the background

def draw_speed(screen):
    #Draws the speed to the display""
    # get the speed...
    values = [0]*8
    for i in range(8):
        values[i] = mcp.read_adc(i)
        #Get's channels
        CHANNEL_ZERO = '{0:>4}'.format(*values) #Voltage out
        CHANNEL_ONE = '{1:>4}'.format(*values) #Raw voltage
        CHANNEL_TWO = '{2:>4}'.format(*values)
        #Overflow Channels
        CHANNEL_THREE = '{3:>4}'.format(*values)
        CHANNEL_FOUR = '{4:>4}'.format(*values) 
        CHANNEL_FIVE = '{5:>4}'.format(*values)
        CHANNEL_SIX = '{6:>4}'.format(*values)
        CHANNEL_SEVEN = '{7:>4}'.format(*values)
        #Makes channels integers to divide later
        CHANNEL_ZERO = int(CHANNEL_ZERO)
        CHANNEL_ONE = int(CHANNEL_ONE)
        CHANNEL_TWO = int(CHANNEL_TWO)
        thermVolts = CHANNEL_TWO *(3.3 / 1023)
        #Temperature affects voltage, -1 degree celcius is a .5 drop in voltage
        #If temp was 20 degrees celcius, therm = .5
        therm = (30 * thermVolts) - 0
        #Fahrenheight to celcius
        therm = round(therm, 0)
        volts = CHANNEL_ONE *(3.3 / 1023) #+ therm
        #Temp is based on a 21 degree celcius temp, multiply accordingly
        temp = (4.246*volts-9.3442)
        #Get's volts data
        speed = math.exp(temp)
        #Get's velocity
        kph = (speed * 1.609)
        velocity = (kph * .278)
        velocity = abs(round(velocity))
        the_speed_string = '{} mps'.format(int(velocity)) # display as whole number
        #Wipes second string
        if velocity == 0:
            the_speed_string = 0
        else:
            font = pygame.font.Font(None, 160)
            text = font.render(the_speed_string, 1, (255, 255, 255))
            textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=screen.get_width()/2, centery=screen.get_height()/2)
            screen.blit(text, textpos)  # paste the text into the background
        #GIVES TEMPERATURE
        the_temp_string = u'{}°F'.format(int(therm))
        if int(therm) == 0:
            the_temp_string = 'ERROR'
        else:
            font = pygame.font.Font(None, 65)
            text = font.render(the_temp_string, 1, (255, 255, 255))
            textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=screen.get_width()-80, centery=screen.get_height()-20)
            screen.blit(text, textpos)  # paste the text into the background


def draw_altitude(screen):
    accel = ADXL345()
    axes1 = accel.getAxes(True)
    x = axes1['x']
    z = axes1['z']
    y = axes1['y']
    #Get's 3D angle
    angle = numpy.angle(x+y+z+1j, deg=True)
    the_altitude_string = u'{} °'.format(round(angle,0))
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 65)
    text = font.render(the_altitude_string, 1, (255, 255, 255))
    textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=120, centery=screen.get_height()-20)
    screen.blit(text, textpos)  # paste the text into the background




def draw_temp(screen):
    #""Draws the temperature to the display
    the_temp = 0
    the_temp_string = u'{}°C'.format(the_temp)
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 65)
    text = font.render(the_temp_string, 1, (255, 255, 255))
    textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=screen.get_width()-80, centery=screen.get_height()-20)
    screen.blit(text, textpos)  # paste the text into the background





if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    size = width, height = 650, 400
    black = 0, 0, 0
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    while True:
        # Checks for key presses, e.g. escape to quit
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: sys.exit()
        # Fill the screen with black background
        screen.fill(black)
        # Draw all the stuff
        draw_borders(screen)
        draw_time(screen)
        draw_speed(screen)
        draw_altitude(screen)
        draw_temp(screen)
        # Update the display
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

As for

> The temperature has a double string

I don't know what you're talking about, but the reason for

> the velocity when zero is blank

is that you explicitly don't draw something on the screen if `velocity == 0` in this part of your code:

```
    if velocity == 0:
        the_speed_string = 0
    else:
        font = pygame.font.Font(None, 160)
        text = font.render(the_speed_string, 1, (255, 255, 255))
        textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=screen.get_width()/2, centery=screen.get_height()/2)
        screen.blit(text, textpos)  # paste the text into the background
```

Maybe you just want to do

```
if velocity == 0:
    the_speed_string = 0

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 160)
text = font.render(the_speed_string, 1, (255, 255, 255))
textpos = text.get_rect(centerx=screen.get_width()/2, centery=screen.get_height()/2)
screen.blit(text, textpos)  # paste the text into the background
```

Comment: I tried that but it still flickered, and by double string I mean one string is permanently 0 and is being over-layed by the correct one.